# CSOM with netcore sending Notification Emails

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver, .net, azure-functions

Utilising the .net framework of the nugget package Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client we were able to send emails with the Utilities class.
Is there any equivalent functionality in the .net standard nugget package?
I am asking because i am tempted to implement some custom remote event receivers with .net core within an azure function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting to this topic, since noone could provide with a better answer.

The best workaround i could find was utilising :

1. Graph API and sending out emails(MS provides fully documented nugget packages for extending functionalities)
   or
2. utilising the power automate, in this case an azure function is not needed.